# Limit what is seen inside a div

Tags: html, css, linq, entity-framework

I have 3 div's images are below.  They pull the entire column and display it.  I need it to only display say 255 characters.  And then I have a Read More link where they can click to go to the full article.

You see how the box on the left has the Read More I would like all 3 boxes to display part of the content and then have the read more link.  The only reason the first box works is because the content is super small to begin with.

The site is HTML5 with CSS and some CSS3.

The information is being pulled in from Entity/LINQ I assume I will need to limit the content there?

Here is one example:

```
    db.TPGForums.Where(m => m.boardID == 11)
      .SelectMany(m => m.TPGForumTopics)
      .SelectMany(m => m.TPGForumPosts)
      .OrderByDescending(p => p.dateCreated)
      .FirstOrDefault();
```

Everything is wrapped in a `<div class="news-block">content</div>`

How can I achieve this?

EDIT:

Another issue that may cause problems is the content being pulled in is HTML Decoded.  So only pulling part of it may cause some HTML Errors on the page with the possibility of some things not being closed properly.  So I think my only option now is to limit it through the size of the div and hide the over flow.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to limit the content where it is being pulled in. Alternatively you could set a max height with overflow hidden and use some sort of a gradient to keep the bottom edge from looking janky. Or you could use `text-overflow: ellipsis`.

Comment: happens all the time with me :)